# Trying to make sure certain symbols aren't in a word

Tags: python

I currently have the following to filter words with square and normal brackets and can't help but think there must be a tidier way to do this..

```
words = [word for word in random.choice(headlines).split(" ")[1:-1] if "[" not in word and "]" not in word and "(" not in word and ")" not in word]
```

I tried creating a list or tuple of symbols and doing

```
if symbol not in word
```

But it dies because I'm comparing a list with a string. I appreciate I could explode this out and do a compare like:

```
for word in random.choice(headlines).split(" ")[1:-1]:
    popIn = 1
    for symbol in symbols: 
        if symbol in word:
            popIn = 0
    if popIn = 1:
        words.append(word)
```

But it seems like overkill in my head. I appreciate I'm a novice programmer so anything I can do to tidy either method up would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use set intersection.

```
brackets = set("[]()")
words = [word for word in random.choice(headlines).split(" ")[1:-1] if not brackets.intersection(word)]
```

The intersection is empty if `word` does not contain any of the characters in `brackets`.

You might also consider using `itertools` instead of a list comprehension.

```
words = list(itertools.ifilterfalse(brackets.intersection,
                                    random.choice(headlines).split(" "))[1:-1]))
```

Comment: Fantastic! I'll try that now.

Comment: Fabulous! Works a treat!

Comment: I do need to look into itertools, I've seen it mentioned all the time but not used it. Next on the list I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want to filter but I advise you to use the [Regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module of python.

```
import re

r = re.compile("\w*[\[\]\(\)]+\w*")
test = ['foo', '[bar]', 'f(o)o']

result = [word for word in test if not r.match(word)]
print result
```

output is *['foo']*